# when I try to use another class the problem show me that error: The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Key'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

```dart
class ColoredCircle extends StatelessWidget {

  ColoredCircle({required Key key, required this.color}) : super(key: key);

  final Color color;
  final double width = 50;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: width ,
        height: width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: Colors.red,
        )
    );
  }
```

Use case

```dart
ColoredCircle(color: Colors.red, key: null),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `required` from `key` on `ColoredCircle` and make it nullable

```dart
class ColoredCircle extends StatelessWidget {
  const ColoredCircle({
    Key? key,
    required this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

Also you can do, by default `StatelessWidget` accept null data.

```dart
class ColoredCircle extends StatelessWidget {
  const ColoredCircle({
    super.key,
    required this.color,
  });
```

More about [`StatelessWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html)

Comment: It's rather about making the value optional via Key? than removing the required keyword.

Comment: @JoRa can follow both  approach that will satisfy your condition.